# method __getattr__ is not inherited from parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, getattr

Trying to subclass [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).Browser class:

```
from mechanize import Browser

class LLManager(Browser, object):
    IS_AUTHORIZED = False
    def __init__(self, login = "", passw = "", *args, **kwargs):
        super(LLManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_handle_robots(False)
```

But when I make something like this:

```
lm["Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title"] = anc
```

then I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    lm["Widget[LinksList]_link_1_title"] = anc
TypeError: 'LLManager' object does not support item assignment
```

Browser class have overridden method `__getattr__` as shown:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    # pass through _form.HTMLForm methods and attributes
    form = self.__dict__.get("form")
    if form is None:
        raise AttributeError(
            "%s instance has no attribute %s (perhaps you forgot to "
            ".select_form()?)" % (self.__class__, name))
    return getattr(form, name)
```

Why my class or instance don't get this method as in parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inherit from object, mechanize.Browser doesn't use new style classes. This should work as expected.

```
from mechanize import Browser

class LLManager(Browser):
    IS_AUTHORIZED = False
    def __init__(self, login = "", passw = "", *args, **kwargs):
        mechanize.Browser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `__setattr__` to support *assignment* in this fashion.  `__getattr__` is only for retrieval

Comment: Browser class have no `__setattr__` methods.

Comment: That's fine, you can create your own if you want.  But this may be a clue that you may not *want* to do that because there's probably a good reason they only have one and not the other.

Comment: What if I want same behaviour as in the parent class? I simply write: `br = Browser(); ...; br["some_input_name"] = "Blah..";` and it works finely for me.

Comment: Pardon.. As **Rosh Oxymoron** said, my target methods are named `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 1):

There's difference between items and attributes. Items are accessed using `ob[item]`, while attributes are accessed using `ob.item`. The methods that define item assignment are `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, and the second is required if you're going to set items, not only access them. The methods `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` deal with attributes, and don't help you here, and besides, the last two should be avoided because they complicate the creation of your class too much.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I knew it but forgot. Does these methods inherits to my class?